# How to build ServiceStack to use it with MonoDroid?

Tags: c#, build, xamarin.android, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I'm trying to use ServiceStack REST DTO and OrmLite with monoDroid.
But I can't fugure out how to build ServiceStack to use it.

By default I have error while deploing to mobile device:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Novell\Novell.MonoDroid.Common.targets(464,2): error : Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'System.Configuration, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?

Comment: http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/monodroid-public-beta

Comment: I just has to build  ServerStack under MonoDroid project settings to use MonoDroid references, then it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here was that you were trying to use a ServiceStack DLL compiled against the full .NET profile from your Mono for Android application, which is destined to fail. In this particular case, it was failing because that DLL had a dependency on System.Configuration, which is not included in the Mono for Android profile. In order to use a library with your application, you should compile its source against the Mono for Android profile, which will verify that the profile supports it, and allow you to safely reference it from your application.

When trying to compile a Mono for Android version of an existing library, the easiest place to start is with the Silverlight build for it (if there is one). Since the Base Class Library exposed by Silverlight is very similar to that of Mono for Android, the set of files/compilation symbols generally lines up between them as well. I have an [old post up here](http://www.gregshackles.com/2010/12/shared-libraries-for-windows-phone-7-monodroid-and-beyond/) that talks about how to link files in from other projects in order to properly compile a class library.